# Check All Checkboxes Issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find out when I click the Check All link it doesn't select ALL the checkboxes on the page. The code for the checkboxes is on the modules.js file. Another issue I've been having is that when you check the checkbox it doesn't work. To check it individually you have to click on the row.

http://jsfiddle.net/YpDdA/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firstly, the .click() isn't attaching to the a because it doesn't exist by the time the script is executed. put all modules.js code inside a $().ready() or use .live instead

also, replacing

```
$('.dataTablePageList').children('tr:eq(0)').find(':checkbox')
```

with

```
$('.dataTablePageList :checkbox')
```

will get you results. .children() doesn't return anything as the tr are not children of the table ,they are descendants. the childrens of the table are a thead and a tbody

using a simple css selector is simpler in this case unless you really have performance issues

Comment: also: attr('checked','checked'). at that point, this refers to the a.checkAll, who doesn't have the attribute checked